# setters and getters in java

Tags: java, getter-setter, setter, getter

I have two files one is the driver, I'm having a problem with setters. It looks did set the value .

```
public class Movie {
private String name;
private int minutes;
protected int tomatoScore;

public Movie(String name, int minutes, int tomatoScore)
{
    this.name=name;
    this.minutes=minutes;
    this.tomatoScore=tomatoScore;
}

public String getName() {return name;}
public void setName(String name) {this.name=name;}
public int getMinutes() {return minutes;}
public boolean setMinutes(int minutes) {return minutes>=0;}
public int getTomatoScore() {return tomatoScore;};
public boolean setTomatoScore(int tomatoScore) {return tomatoScore>=0 &&tomatoScore<=100;};
public boolean isFresh() {return tomatoScore>=60;};

public void display()
{
    //this.name = name;
    //this.minutes = minutes;
    //this.tomatoScore =tomatoScore;

    System.out.println("Movie: "+ getName());
    System.out.println("Length: "+ getMinutes() +"min.");

    if(tomatoScore>=60)
    {
        System.out.println("TomatoScore: Fresh");
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("TomatoScore: Rotten");
    }


}
```

}

and bellow is the driver file if you notice the setters did do the job that is supposed to do I believe the problem is movie class, if you run the driver to test the program you see if you set the value to the negative the if statement does not function properly.( setMinutes and setTomatoScore are wrong. They do not set the class fields at all)

public class MovieDriver {

```
public static void main (String [] args){

    Movie[] myCollection = new Movie[5];
    myCollection[0] = new Movie("Batman The Dark Knight", 152, 94);
    myCollection[1] = new Movie("Guardians of the Galaxy", 125, 91);
    myCollection[2] = new Movie("The GodFather", 178, 98);
    myCollection[3] = new Movie("Suicide Squad", 137, 27);
    myCollection[4] = new Movie("Get out", 104, 99);


    //TODO
    //Initialize the variable below and add it to myCollection at index 4.
    //You can pick any movie you wish.
    Movie yourMovie;


    System.out.println("Here are all the movies in my collection of movies.\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < myCollection.length; i++) {
        if(myCollection[i] != null)
            myCollection[i].display();
    }

    System.out.println("_______________________________________________");


    System.out.println("\nHere are the Fresh movies.");

    for(int i = 0; i < myCollection.length; i++) {
        if(myCollection[i] != null && myCollection[i].isFresh()) {
            System.out.println(myCollection[i].getName() + " is fresh.");
        }
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Here are the Rotten movies.");

    for(Movie movieTmp: myCollection){
        if (movieTmp != null && !movieTmp.isFresh())
            System.out.println(movieTmp.getName() + " is rotten.");
    }

    System.out.println("_______________________________________________\n");

    Movie harryPotter = new Movie("Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban", 144, 91);
    System.out.println("The movie " + harryPotter.getName() + " was created.\n");

    System.out.println("Is " + harryPotter.getName() + " a long movie?");

    if(harryPotter.getMinutes() > 120) {
        System.out.println("Yes, it is a bit long.\n");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Nope, that isn't too bad.\n");
    }

    System.out.println("Can I set the minutes of " + harryPotter.getName() + " to a negative number?");
    harryPotter.setMinutes(-5);

    if(harryPotter.getMinutes() == -5) {
        System.out.println("It worked. The runtime is -5 minutes.\n");
    } else {
        System.out.println("It did NOT work.  Negative runtimes are not allowed.\n");
    }

    System.out.println("Can I set tomato score of " + harryPotter.getName() + " to a negative number?");
    harryPotter.setTomatoScore(-100);

    if(harryPotter.getTomatoScore() == -100) {
        System.out.println("It worked. The score is -100.  This movie is terrible according to the site.\n");
    } else {
        System.out.println("It did NOT work.  Negative scores are not allowed.\n");
    }

    System.out.println("Can I set tomato score of " + harryPotter.getName() + " to a number greater than 100?");
    harryPotter.setTomatoScore(101);

    if(harryPotter.getTomatoScore() == 101) {
        System.out.println("It worked. The score is 101.  Best Harry Potter movie ever!\n");
    } else {
        System.out.println("It did NOT work.  Still the best Harry Potter movie out all the movies though.\n");
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Your `setMinutes` and `setTomatoScore` methods don't set anything, they just return a boolean. I assume you've forgotten to add `this.tomatoScore = tomatoScore` for example.

Comment: There is a restriction on  setMinutes , the negative numbers are not allowed. setTomatoScore, the restrictions are no negative number and no number over 100.

Comment: okay... then do that check AND write 'this.tomatoScore = tomatoScore'. If you don't, you just check and then discard the input.

Answer (score 0):

As rzwitserloot mentioned, setter function for minutes and tomatoScore are not setting any thing.This might be the case.

Additional I would like add, I found it is better to use well known IDE for java programming like intellij, netBean, eclipse. They have provide many feature like auto generate  setter, getter , constructor. So we can focus more on core logic and this saves our time and reduce possiblity of manual error.
One more point I would like to add,
It is better to use setter in the constructor, so before setting value is we want to perform any input validation,we can have that in setter and can use that even when setting value via constructor.

For an example,

```
public class Example {
private int x;
public Movie(int x){setMinutes(x);}
public void setX(int x) {
//some validation on input
  if(x >= 0){this.x = x;}
public int getX() {return x;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need this:

```
       public boolean setMinutes(int minutes) {
          if(minutes >= 0 && minutes < 60) { 
    //I'm guessing the <60 part here, but whatever, 
    //this is how you'd set the 100 limit on your setTomatoScore method
            this.minutes = minutes;
            return true;
          }
          return false;
        }
```

Make similar corrections for the `setTomatoScore`

Answer (score 0):

​You need to set something `tomatoScore` in the state of methods as shown below​​ :

```
public boolean setTomatoScore(int tomatoScore) {
  if (tomatoScore >= 0 && tomatoScore <= 100) {
    this.tomatoScore = tomatoScore;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```